# Где и как лучше прехватывать/обрабатывать исключения?

Tags: php

Хочу разобраться, как и где лучше/правильней обрабатывать исключения и что отдавать пользователю.

Есть код, он должен сохранить пользователя.
В этом примере мы можем получить `Exception` в 3 разных местах.

Как я сейчас представляю, обернуть вызов метода сервиса в контроллере в `try catch`. Поскольку в обязанность контроллера входит генерирование ответа пользователю в зависимости от результата. Но, меня смущают некоторые нюансы:

- В случаи большого количества возможных исключений методы контроллера превратятся в простыню из `catch`.
- Еще и ошибку нужно записать в лог.

Если обрабатывать ошибку по месту, возникает проблема в возврате обратно данных по цепочке. Это наплодит кучу `if`-ов и усложнит разные методы разными типами возврата.

Если поместить `try catch` в сервис и возвращать контроллеру к примеру `User|false`, как тогда контроллер будет генерировать ответ, если он не будет знать в чем проблема, в базе или в том, что это дубликат.

Может лучшим способом будет обрабатывать все ошибки через `set_exception_handler`?

```
class UserController
{
    private UserSerivce $service;

    public function store(array $data)
    {
        $user = $this->service->new($data);

        return redirect()->to('/' . $user->id);
    }
}

class UserSerivce
{
    private UserRepository $repository;

    public function new(array $data): User
    {
        $user = new User($data['name']); //InvalidArgumentException

        $user = $this->repository->add($user);

        return $user;
    }
}

class UserRepository
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->builder = new PDO(''); //PDOException
    }
    public function add(User $user): User
    {
        $saved = $this->builder->query('INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ("user")'); //PDOException
    }
}

class User
{
    private string $name;

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        if (empty($name)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Name is empty');
        }
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
```

Comment: У себя обработку ошибок я делал в слое Middleware. В это случае у вас все контроллеры будут чистенькие

Comment: @ArchDemon скажите, а что это значит? можете пример написать в ответе? мне тоже интересная эта тема и я не понимаю что значит Middlware. Точнее как это происходит. Как можно сделать и контроллеры и сервисы чистыми и что-то обработать где-то в посреднике. Это же надо что-то перехватывать? А что делать тем более если есть кастомные эксепшены сообщения которых надо будет выводить пользователю? Напишите пожалуйста) очень интересно)